# HTML/CSS Responsive buttons at 50% width

Tags: html, css

can anyone help me been trying to create a custom navigation that displays 2 buttons side-by-side no matter what the screen size and I use this css code:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 50%;
padding: 10px;
```

But every time I use this, the other buttons seems to go to a new line.

I want it to look like [image: this]

no matter what the screen size is. 2 buttons side-by-side that each one would take up half the screen.

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
    font-size: 0;
}
button {
    font-size: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 20px);
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button>button1</button>
    <button>button2</button>
</div>
```

or

```css
div {
    display: flex;
}
button {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <button>button1</button>
    <button>button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this but is there a way it would still have a space between the buttons? Also what does flex-grow do? I'm still learning how to code HTML and CSS

Comment: @Paolo07 `flex-grow` can be left out after the width is set, Button gap add `margin` is good, but I still recommend you learn the basics from HTML and CSS. The above code has been updated.

Comment: @Paolo07 After the basics of HTML and CSS are learned, common styling problems can be solved.